What is the vanishing ideal of a product of real circles (bis)?
My precedent question was closed for being too vague, so I added some details.
For my research, I need to know the necessary and sufficient conditions for a trigonometric polynomial in $n$ variables to always evaluate at zero. Although this is a pretty natural question, I didn't manage to find anything online.
Since I've been asked to clarify: what I call a trigonometric polynomial is a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[X_1, Y_1, \ldots, X_n, Y_n]$ evaluated at $(X_i, Y_i) = (\cos(\theta_i), \sin(\theta_i))$ for variable angles $\theta_i$. Hence my question boils down to finding the polynomials that vanish on a product of real circles.
I've tried to address the problem with algebraic geometry, but I only know the basics.
For a (real or complex) algebraic variety $V$, I denote by $I(V)$ the polynomial ideal that vanishes on $V$. Reciprocally, for a polynomial ideal $I$, I denote by $V(I)$ the algebraic variety defined by the points where all polynomials in $I$ vanish.
If $V$ is a product of complex circles, it's quite simple because we can use the Nullstellensatz on $\mathbb{C}$: we need to find $I(V(I))$ where $I = (X_1^2 + Y_1^2 - 1, \ldots, X_n^2 + Y_n^2 - 1) \subseteq \mathbb{C}[X_1, Y_1, \ldots, X_n, Y_n]$. One can show that $I$ is prime, so $I$ is its own radical, and the vanishing ideal is $I$ itself by the Nullstellensatz.
If $V$ is a product of real circles though, I only found the theorem known as the Real Nullstellensatz which states that one just needs to replace the radical by the so called "real radical".
$$\sqrt{I}^{\mathbb{R}} = \{P \in \mathbb{R}[X_1, Y_1, \ldots, X_n, Y_n] \mid \exists m \in \mathbb{N}, h_1, \ldots, h_r \in \mathbb{R}[X_1, Y_1, \ldots, X_n, Y_n], g \in I, P^{2m} = -\sum_{i=1}^rh_i^2 - g\}.$$
I have no idea how to compute this real radical, nor do I know if my way of addressing the problem is completely overkill.
My intuition is that this should still be $I$, since the polynomials $X_i^2 + Y_i^2 - 1$ really seem to be minimal to characterize a product of circle, but I can't prove it.
Could anybody either help me with computing this set, or point me out to a resource where this problem is tackled ?

This is (up to some very minor alterations) exactly your previous post. Please don't repost a closed question - instead, please improve your closed question via an edit.
